# Changed svn commit message doesn't show in log

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

For some reason SVN doesn't want to search and show changed commit messages, it behaves as if the original message is still relevant. Steps I take:

1. I commit in SVN. Let's say I commit with a message containing following string: `MS-1348`
2. Afterwards I change the commit message, changing `MS-1348` into `MAX-87`.
3. When I open log using TortoiseSVN and search for `MAX-87` I get nothing (even after `Show All`). But if I search using the old `MS-1348` I still get to see the revisions.
4. Another interesting tidbit: if I go to `Edit log messages` I will see the **new** message (containing `MAX-87`).

Is there a way to make SVN behave like you would expect it to and show the new string / search by new string? Perhaps something is cached somewhere?

[image]

Comment: Did you run `SVN Update` after editing the log message?

Comment: Yes, no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tortoise-svn's log-caching can cause this behaviour. clear the cache and try again.

Comment: It worked. Went to `Settings -> Saved Data -> Log messages (Show log dialog) -> Clear`.